# Row value and Column header join to get the total Old Employee count in Excel

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a situation where i have 2 different result set

1)First Data Set showing the total_employee per month.
2) Second data set the total experience employee percentage per month.

What i wanted is below

Input:

[image]

Output:

[image]

Output logic will be multiplied between Input1 and Input 2 Based on Date and Header and will be the old Customers number

Ex: Total Employee_A for Date= 2019-01-01 is 100 
    Total Experience_Employee_A % for Date ='2019-01-01 ' is 0.95

Output should be Total_Old_employee_A *Total_OlDEmployee_A Percentage.

(100*.95)=95 as per output.

Can anybody kindly help me for the same

Regards,
Debayan

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your data sample i think you have same date entries in both the tables. If so use below array formula : =IF(F2=A2:A4,(C2+(H2*C2)),0) it will work.. Please revert if i took your problem wrongly

Assumption : your first input table is available in column A : E and next table is in column F: J. Type the given formula in column F and do not forget to press CTRL+SHFT+Enter